# Ruby Number Guessing Game

Tags: ruby

I have tried to make a number guessing game using ruby but it seems to be looping all over again after the user gets the correct answer, here's my code and thanks in advance!

```
require './input_functions'

def check (rno,input)
    x = 1
    
    while (x == 1)  
        y = 0
        if (rno > input)
            puts("Try a bigger number")
            input = gets.chomp.to_i
            y = y + 1
            x = 1
        else
            if (rno < input)
                puts("Try a smaller number")
                input = gets.chomp.to_i
                y = y + 1
                x = 1
            else
                if(rno == input)    
                puts("Bingo!")
                x = 0
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return 
end


def main
    rno = rand(100)
        
    input = read_integer("Enter an integer between 0 and 100: ")
    check(rno,input,y)
    
    times = check(rno,input,y)
    puts ("You have tried " + times.to_s + " times.")
    
end

main
```

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: Also, your error description is unclear: what does it mean that it "seems" to be looping all over again? So, do you mean that it *does not* loop, but it only *looks like* it loops? https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: hi, sry abt that, am still new to stackoverflow. and no it is looping but it wont stop looping even after the number equals to the random number generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problems are:

- You call `check` method two times within `main` method, you need to remove the first one.
- You need to move `y = 0` out of `while` loop to be able to `return` it.

Tried to simplify your code a bit, and you could try to improve it even more.

```rb
def check(rno, input)
  x = 1
  y = 0
    
  while x == 1      
    if rno == input
      puts "Bingo!"
      x = 0
    else
      if rno > input
        puts "Try a bigger number"
      else
        puts "Try a smaller number"
      end
      
      input = gets.chomp.to_i
      y = y + 1   
    end
  end
    
  return y
end

def main
  rno = rand(100)
  input = read_integer("Enter an integer between 0 and 100: ")
    
  times = check(rno, input)
  puts ("You have tried " + times.to_s + " times.")
end
```